# How to get length of the text inside for loop

Tags: python, count

how can I get the length of the text of all document in one line if I'm using the for loop to extract the text before that?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Olympus,_Utah'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

text = soup.find_all('p')

for text2 in text:
    r = text2.get_text().split()
    print(len(r))
```

output:

```
117
23
84
73
66
69
9
```

Problem is that it's counting every line. I want length of the document in one line like this:

```
441
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with sum() -

```py
print(sum([len(text2.get_text().split()) for text2 in text]))
```

so, first you iterate through text - `for text2 in text`

then, you extract text with .get_text() method, split it, and its length gets stored as an element in the list - `len(text2.get_text().split())`

then using sum(), you sum all elements of that array, and finally print it

edit: just to be clear, that one liner replaces whole for loop

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Olympus,_Utah'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

text = soup.find_all('p')
sum = 0
for text2 in text:
    r = text2.get_text().split()
    sum= sum + len(r)
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sum them up:

```
total_length = 0
for text2 in text:
    r = text2.get_text().split()
    total_length += len(r)
print(total_length)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can ad a variable `total_len` and increment it by the element length for every element

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Olympus,_Utah'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

text = soup.find_all('p')

total_len = 0
for text2 in text:
    r = text2.get_text().split()
    total_len += len(r)

print(total_len)
```